# Naming conflict with File extension and Shebang in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ksh

I have seen some Linux scripts having Shebang different from the file extension.

Ex:

- somefile.sh has `#!/bin/bash` inside it
- somefile.ksh has `#!/bin/sh` inside it
- somefile.bash has `#!/bin/sh` inside it

Can someone tell me what is proper naming convention to be followed while mentioning file extension and Shebang inside it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation between extension and shebang. Extensions are for users only.

Also for `bash` files you can use `#!/bin/bash`. And `/bin/sh` is usually a symbolic link to `/bin/bash` or `/bin/dash`, depends upon the system.